How pathological are the $L^{p}$ functions?
The motivation for my question is simple: for Riemann integrable functions, we had, at worst, almost everywhere continuity. It's not that bad behavior wise, but it is integration wise. So we come up with $L^{p}$ functions, that need not be continuous anywhere. Of course $L^{p}$ is way bigger than $C_{c}$ (set of continuous functions with compact support, the ideally Riemann integrable functions), but how pathological do the functions we've brought into the mix generally get? I know that we can go around the issue approximating functions in $L^{p}$ through those in $C_{c},$ my main interest is in how "bad" things get from here on. Thanks in advance.

It depends on what you mean by "bad". According to Lusin's theorem, every measurable function is "almost continuous" in a certain specific sense, so in this sense they are good. Since you mentioned approximation, we also know that $C^{\infty}_c(\Bbb R^n)$ is dense in $L^p(\Bbb R^n)$, so each $L^p$ function can be nicely approximated. It seems you are aware that $L^p$ functions can be discontinuous everywhere, so maybe in that sense they are pathological. It all depends on the perspective, really.

^ it really is perspective. And one of the key takeaways from Lebesgue theory is that the precise pointwise behaviour is not really what matters for a lot of purposes, so analyzing goodness/badness in this regard isn’t really beneficial (for the purposes of integration). Instead you look at the Lebesgue spaces as a whole (wonderful properties). Or you look at limiting properties of sequences of functions (again very nice properties). Or you look at more specific classes of functions defined by integral norms (e.g Sobolev spaces, which are Very good and flexible for hardcore PDE analysis).

@BigbearZzz I get you. What I meant by "pathological" is a function that behaves erratically. I confess I don't have an example, but I'm referring to the function's behavior outside of integration.

As far as badness from a pointwise sense, I like (indicator functions of) the fat Cantor set, or even a “well-distributed fat Cantor set” (i.e the infamous Rudin RCA chapter 2 problem 8). And I like the devil’s staircase. These are the seeds of some of the more unintuitive (counter)examples in analysis.

@peek-a-boo You put perfectly what I'm reffering to in the question. I understand that for integration purposes, we're in a very good environment, with wonderful properties, one of which is that the behavior of the function itself doesn't really matter much for its integrability. But since we threw continuity out of the window, I'd expect that some pretty badly behaved functions came to be integrable, but I can't find examples outside of the standard ones (dirichlet, volterra's function's derivative, etc)

@GustavodeSouza Perhaps you might be interested in reading about Baire classes. Maybe that is related to what you might be looking for (and while you're at it, also read about Borel hierarchy if you're into weird sets).

There exist $L^p$ functions which are unbounded in every subinterval

Quiet opposite. I think $C^0$ are more pathological than $L^p$ when $1<p<\infty$. Because it fails to peserve singular integral. Basically Hilbert transform is $L^p$ bounded but never $C^0$ bounded.

@BigbearZzz checked out Baire classes of functions. Even though I don't have experience with transfinite induction, it does seem to be in line with I'm looking for. I'll keep looking at it

@RohanDidmishe I'm looking for something like those, yes

@LidingYao Looked it up, wasn't familiar with Hilbert transform. While I do understand what you're saying, I'm looking for "bad-behavior" outside the realm of integration.  I might be failing to appreciate your example outta of ignorance on the subject, so if I'm, I apologize

There exists an $F \in L^1([0,1])$ unbounded in every subinterval, which cannot be made bounded by changing values on a measure $0$ set.
Proof:
Let $\varphi^{a}_n: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by:
\begin{align*}
    \varphi^a_n(x) =
    \begin{cases}
    0,\ \text{if}\ x \not\in \left[a-\frac{1}{4^n}, a+\frac{1}{4^n}\right]\\
    n - 4^n n |x-a|,\ \text{if}\ x \in \left[a-\frac{1}{4^n}, a+\frac{1}{4^n}\right]
    \end{cases}
\end{align*}
Clearly $\varphi^a_n \geq 0$ is continuous for any $a \in \mathbb{R}\ \text{and}\ n \in \mathbb{R}$.
Also note that we have:
\begin{align*}
    \varphi^a_n(x) \geq \frac{n}{2},\ \text{if}\ x \in \left[a-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}, a+\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\right]
\end{align*}
Define $f_n: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as:
\begin{align*}
    f_n(x) = \sum^{2^n -1}_{j=1} \varphi^{j/2^n}_n(x)
\end{align*}
Similarly note that:
\begin{align*}
    f_n(x) \geq \frac{n}{2}, \forall x \in \bigcup^{2^n-1}_{j=1}\left[\frac{j}{2^n}-\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}, \frac{j}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{2n+1}}\right]
\end{align*}
Define $F_N: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ :
\begin{align*}
    F_N(x) = \sum^N_{n=1} f_n(x)
\end{align*}
$F_N$" />
$F_N$" />
$F_N$" />
Now we can see that:
\begin{align*}
    \int^1_0 |f_n| \ dx = \int^1_0 f_n \ dx = \sum^{2^n -1}_{j=1} \int^1_0 \varphi_n^{j/2^n} \ dx =  \sum^{2^n -1}_{j=1} \frac{2n}{4^n} - \frac{n}{4^n} \leq \frac{n}{2^n}
\end{align*}
which is a sequence of continuous functions.
Note that $2^n \geq (n-2)^3/6,\ \text{for all}\ n \geq 3$. Hence the sequence of partial sums:
\begin{align*}
    0<\sum^N_{n=3} \frac{n}{2^n}  =  \sum^N_{n=3} \frac{n-2}{2^n}  + \sum^N_{n=3} \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} \leq  \sum^N_{n=3} \frac{6}{(n-2)^2}  + 1 \leq \pi^2 + 1
\end{align*}
is bounded above. Hence the series converges by monotone convergence theorem, and by Cauchy criterion, given $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists N'' \in \mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align*}
    \sum^{N}_{k=M+1} \frac{k}{2^k} < \epsilon
\end{align*}
for $N,M \geq N''$
From this fact, we see $F_n$ is a Cauchy sequence of continuous functions in the $L^1$ norm.
Now, from the completeness of $L^1$ in the Lebesgue sense, there exists a function $F:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is Lebesgue measurable and in $L^1$, and $||F_N-F|| \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$.
This $F$ can be shown to be unbounded in every subinterval
Inspired by:
https://personal.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m420/incomplete.pdf
which has another example

Damn. Yes, that is that is the type of "pathology" I had in mind: a function which behaves badly, but it is integrable. Thanks for taking the time to give this example
